# Adding the canvas platform to an existing Facebook App

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

I have an existing Facebook App which is set up for an iOS and Android app. 
I want to lever the Notifications API which seems to be limited to (Facebook) apps which make use of the Canvas platform.

My question is - are there any pitfalls I should look out for when enabling the Canvas platform for this Facebook app? I don't want to disrupt the existing platforms as we use Facebook for authentication on our iOS and Android apps.

Comment: You can add platform any time, it doesn’t affect your existing ones. But be careful, if you set up a “dummy” canvas for this purpose only, Facebook might ask you to remove it next time you submit any part of your app for review – they want your app to present actual functionality on each platform.

Comment: OK @CBroe I will keep that in mind. We can certainly give the canvas app functionality relevant to our app(s). I just noticed that airbnb seem to have a canvas 'game' which consists on an information page and no game. I'm guessing that this is get the functionality they need from the Graph API.